# magento-checkout: ammount until free shipping

Tags: magento

Im seeking for a way to output the ammount thats left untill one may have free shipping. Example:

Your checkout is 28 € / Free-shipping is 30 €
The message (on onepage-checkout-pacge) would read: "Hey, 2 € left until free shipping". 
Is there a plugin or a way to modify the onepagecheckout-template?

Best regards 
Benedikt

Comment: Dont you think its very easy. Just get your subtotal and freeshipping amount. Calculate it and show. Or best way is to add small jquery code which will get the subtotal and freeshipping, do the calculation and show it. You have not done some research or posted any code. Show what you have tried.

Comment: hello Kingshuk Deb, thanks for your reply. I did some research on that topic, but I did not really find a good point to statr from. Actualy you are right, I did not perform changes on my code so far. Maybe you had an idea where I could start my research? If you know a tutorial for example, that would be very helpful for me.

Comment: I think i have told you everything you need. Just search on google how to get cart subtotal or freeshipping amount. And after that select if you want to do it using JS or Php. And then do it. Simple.

Comment: Ok, Im quite shure its not that simple, but ill give it a try. thanks